# Reading CSV file and splitting it in an array(Java)

Tags: java, csv

Here is my current code:

```
public static String findPhoneNumber(Scanner input, String name) {
    String[] arr;
    while (input.hasNextLine()){
        arr = name.split(DELIMITER);
        input.nextLine();
        for (int i=0;i<=arr.length;i++) {
            if (arr[0].endsWith(name)) {
                return (arr[3]);
            }
            else {
                return("Nothing to return");
            }
        }
    }
    CSV.testFindPhoneNumber(arr[3]);
}


package com.company;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CSV {
public static final String CSV_FILE_URL = "https://orb.essex.ac.uk/ce/ce152/data/staff.csv";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(CSV_FILE_URL);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    testFindPhoneNumber(input);
}

public static void testFindPhoneNumber(Scanner input){
    System.out.println("### Testing findPhoneNumber");
    for (String name : new String[]{"Kruschwitz", "Vickers", "Voelker"}){
        String result = TestCSV.findPhoneNumber(input,name);
        System.out.println("name= " + name + ", result= " + result);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to split the excel file(the URL which I have in my code) to a 3 element array and then find the names written in public class CSV to print their corresponding phone numbers of those names.

Don't know exactly how to do that. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: A) never *link* to your source code - instead put it (well formatted) into your question B) explain why your code is not working - this is not a site where you drop requirements and we do the work for you C) there are tons and tons of existing CSV parsers out there ... try using one of those.

Comment: @GhostCat I suppose I need to return the value of the arr[3] to my CSV class, can't quite seem to understand how it works yet. And I''m not actually asking for someone to tell me how to do the whole thing, I just need advice on how to improve this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept. But keep in mind: such "code review" for such *low quality* input is really the exception here. You absolutely should try to go in smaller steps, and get those smaller things working for yourself (or put a very specific question around **one** failing aspect of your program here). Please understand that this community is for "professionals and enthusiastic amateurs"; it is **not** targetting newbies who are struggling with the very first basic steps. But as said: glad that I could help; and that you accepted that quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main class i.e., **CSV** looks fine to me. The issue is with the method **findPhoneNumber** which is getting invoked in main class. Below is the rectified version of it.

```
    public static String findPhoneNumber(Scanner input, String name){
        String[] arr;
        String phoneNum = null;
        while (input.hasNextLine()){
            arr = input.nextLine().split(",");
            if (arr[0].endsWith(name)) {
                phoneNum = arr[2];
                break;
            }
        }
        return phoneNum;
    }
```

Here is the output.

> Testing findPhoneNumber
>
> name= Kruschwitz, result= 5A.542
>
> name= Vickers, result= 5A.528
>
> name= Voelker, result= null

Answer (score 0):

There are many many things wrong with your code. Lets quickly go over the most important things:

```
public static String findPhoneNumber(Scanner input, String name) {
String[] arr;
```

Bad naming. What is *arr* supposed to do? Give it a name that tells what it is supposed to mean.

```
while (input.hasNextLine()){
    arr = name.split(DELIMITER);
```

Why are you splitting **name**? The name is a fixed parameter coming into your method?!

```
    input.nextLine();
```

You are reading a line ... but not storing that result. In other words: you read the whole input, but don't process **any** of that.

Probably you mean `String line = input.nextLine()`; and afterwards your method would want to work on that `line` coming from the URL-file.

```
    for (int i=0;i<=arr.length;i++) {
        if (arr[0].endsWith(name)) {
            return (arr[3]);
        }
        else {
            return("Nothing to return");
        }
    }
```

I have no idea what you want to achieve with that comparison. And then: **never** return some "message" to indicate an error (for a method that returns a string). How is the caller of that method supposed to understand that something went wrong?

So: instead of returning a message, throw an exception or return null.

Finally: you are completely overburdering yourself. Dont try to read CSV from a remote URL, split and process that input all in ONE step. Instead: first write code that just reads that URL and maybe *prints* the data. Then, when that works nicely, write separate code that does the "matching" you want to do on plain string input. And then finally, bring those things together.

But **again**: a simple `split(",")` does **not** work for arbitrary CSV data. CSV is much more complicated. Don't try to re-invent the wheel; especially when you are on such a beginner level.

Comment: Thank you for that, i'll consider what you mentioned above.